# add two variadic template list of integers

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Given this type

```
template<std::size_t N, int ...content>
struct list {
    inline int reduce() {
        int result = 0;
        constexpr int arr[N] = { content... };
        for(std::size_t k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
            result += arr[k];
        }

        return result;
    }
};
```

I'd like to implement a function `add`, which returns a new list containing the element-by-element addition of the two input lists. 
In other words (pseudo-code):

```
add([a0, a1, a2], [b0, b1]) -> [a0 + b0, a1 + b2, a2]
```

Problem:

- I don't even know how to declare the return type of such a function
- and i don't know if it's possible

Comment: I don't get why it returns an int and not a list<N, int...>

Comment: Sorry, had a brain fart. Will write an answer in a moment.

Comment: ot: you dont need the `inline`. actually I am a bit surprised that it is even allowed in that place

Comment: edited my code (renamed sum to reduce) to prevent this kind of mis interpretation

Comment: How is the `reduce` function related to your problem?

Comment: `reduce` is a red herring; it's a completely different operation. Do you want your result to be a type or a value? You said that it should produce "a new list", but then it's not really a function, if it's supposed to put everything in a type. A value of type `list<...>` is as good as the type itself.

Comment: I'd be interested in what you do in particular.

Comment: reduce is just here to show I'm not a complete fool with variadic templates. I tried stuff, but failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t N, int ...content>
struct list {
    inline int reduce() {
        int result = 0;
        constexpr int arr[N] = { content... };
        for(std::size_t k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
            result += arr[k];
        }

        return result;
    }
};


template <std::size_t I, int ...A>
constexpr int list_at(list<sizeof...(A),A...>)
{
    if constexpr (I < sizeof...(A))
    {
        constexpr int arr[] {A...};
        return arr[I];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

template <int ...A, int ...B, std::size_t ...I>
constexpr auto list_sum_low(list<sizeof...(A),A...>,
                            list<sizeof...(B),B...>,
                            std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return list<sizeof...(I), (list_at<I>(list<sizeof...(A),A...>{}) +
                               list_at<I>(list<sizeof...(B),B...>{}))...>{};
}

template <int ...A, int ...B>
constexpr auto list_sum(list<sizeof...(A),A...>, list<sizeof...(B),B...>)
{
    constexpr int a = sizeof...(A), b = sizeof...(B);
    return list_sum_low(list<a,A...>{}, list<b,B...>{},
                        std::make_index_sequence<(a > b ? a : b)>{});
}


template <int ...A>
void print_list(list<sizeof...(A),A...>)
{
    (void(std::cout << ' ' << A) , ...);
}


int main()
{
    constexpr auto x = list_sum(list<4, 1,2,3,4>{}, list<2, 10,20>{});
    print_list(x);
}
```

Also, note that there is no need have `size_t N` template parameter for `class list`. Parameter packs know their own size.

Comment: Or we could use the array initialization rules to do the padding. I don't think it gets much simpler than [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0sSNOg9zA9cHqQjE) :-).

Answer (score 3):

Just another solution, based on good old *partial specialization*:

```
template <size_t N, int... E> struct list { };

template <typename, typename> struct list_cat;

template <size_t N1, int... E1, size_t N2, int... E2>
struct list_cat<list<N1, E1...>, list<N2, E2...>>
{ using type = list<N1 + N2, E1..., E2...>; };

template <typename, typename> struct list_add;

template <size_t N1, int E1H, int... E1T, size_t N2, int E2H, int... E2T>
struct list_add<list<N1, E1H, E1T...>, list<N2, E2H, E2T...>>
{
  using type = typename list_cat<
    list<1, E1H + E2H>,
    typename list_add<list<N1 - 1, E1T...>, list<N2 - 1, E2T...>>::type
  >::type;
};

template <size_t N2, int... E2>
struct list_add<list<0>, list<N2, E2...>> { using type = list<N2, E2...>; };

template <size_t N1, int... E1>
struct list_add<list<N1, E1...>, list<0>> { using type = list<N1, E1...>; };

template <>
struct list_add<list<0>, list<0>> { using type = list<0>; }
```

Which can be used as:

```
using L1 = list<3, -1, -2, -3>;
using L2 = list <2, 10, 20>;
using L = typename list_add<L1, L2>::type;
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/x8LYcoC3lWu51Gqo

Comment: This is much nicer than the `integer_sequence` IMHO. I started writing one that was [very similar](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b367a4a6b9514499), but had to go out for a while and obviously someone snatched the idea. Good job! :)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz That happens to me all the time. People tend to be freakishly quick here on SO ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution `std::integer_sequence` based.

When the dimension of the two lists is the same, an `add()` function is trivially simple

```
template <std::size_t N, int ... Is1, int ... Is2>
constexpr auto add (list<N, Is1...>, list<N, Is2...>)
 { return list<N, Is1+Is2...>{}; }
```

The problem is when we have lists of different length.

A possible solution is extend the shorter list with zeros and apply the preceding function to the length-uniformed lists.

Given a extender as follows

```
template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N0, int ... Is, std::size_t ... Js>
constexpr auto listExtend (list<N0, Is...>, std::index_sequence<Js...>)
 { return list<N1, Is..., ((void)Js, 0)...>{}; }

template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N0, int ... Is,
          std::enable_if_t<(N1 > N0), bool> = true>
constexpr auto listExtend (list<N0, Is...> l)
 { return listExtend<N1>(l, std::make_index_sequence<N1-N0>{}); }
```

we need only to add the following `add()` functions

```
template <std::size_t N1, int ... Is1, std::size_t N2, int ... Is2,
          std::enable_if_t<(N1 > N2), bool> = true>
constexpr auto add (list<N1, Is1...> l1, list<N2, Is2...> l2)
 { return add(l1, listExtend<N1>(l2)); }

template <std::size_t N1, int ... Is1, std::size_t N2, int ... Is2,
          std::enable_if_t<(N1 < N2), bool> = true>
constexpr auto add (list<N1, Is1...> l1, list<N2, Is2...> l2)
 { return add(listExtend<N2>(l1), l2); }
```

The following is a full compiling C++14 (unfortunately `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence` require C++14) example

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t, int ...>
struct list
 { };

template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N0, int ... Is, std::size_t ... Js>
constexpr auto listExtend (list<N0, Is...>, std::index_sequence<Js...>)
 { return list<N1, Is..., ((void)Js, 0)...>{}; }

template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N0, int ... Is,
          std::enable_if_t<(N1 > N0), bool> = true>
constexpr auto listExtend (list<N0, Is...> l)
 { return listExtend<N1>(l, std::make_index_sequence<N1-N0>{}); }

template <std::size_t N, int ... Is1, int ... Is2>
constexpr auto add (list<N, Is1...>, list<N, Is2...>)
 { return list<N, Is1+Is2...>{}; }

template <std::size_t N1, int ... Is1, std::size_t N2, int ... Is2,
          std::enable_if_t<(N1 > N2), bool> = true>
constexpr auto add (list<N1, Is1...> l1, list<N2, Is2...> l2)
 { return add(l1, listExtend<N1>(l2)); }

template <std::size_t N1, int ... Is1, std::size_t N2, int ... Is2,
          std::enable_if_t<(N1 < N2), bool> = true>
constexpr auto add (list<N1, Is1...> l1, list<N2, Is2...> l2)
 { return add(listExtend<N2>(l1), l2); }

int main ()
 {
   list<3u, 1, 2, 3> l1;
   list<2u, 10, 20>  l2;

   auto l3 = add(l1, l2);

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(l3), list<3u, 11, 22, 3>>::value,
                  "!" );
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I will use `std::integer_sequence`:

```
template <int ... Is>
using int_sequence = std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>;
```

When size match, it would be easy, so create method to increase size and fill with zero:

```
template <int... Is, int... Zeros>
int_sequence<Is..., (0 * Zeros)...>
fill_with_zero(int_sequence<Is...>, int_sequence<Zeros...>) { return {}; }

template <std::size_t N, int... Is>
auto fill_with_zero_to_reach(int_sequence<Is...> seq)
-> decltype(fill_with_zero(seq,
                           std::make_integer_sequence<int,
                                                      (sizeof...(Is) < N
                                                       ? N - sizeof...(Is)
                                                       : 0)>{}))
{
    return {};
}
```

Then the addition:

```
// simple case, sizes match:
template <int... Is1, int... Is2,
          std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Is1) == sizeof...(Is2), int> = 0>
int_sequence<(Is1 + Is2)...>
add(int_sequence<Is1...>, int_sequence<Is2...>) { return {}; }

// sizes mismatch:
template <int... Is1, int... Is2,
          std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Is1) != sizeof...(Is2), int> = 0>
auto
add(int_sequence<Is1...> seq1, int_sequence<Is2...> seq2)
-> decltype(add(fill_with_zero_to_reach<std::max(sizeof...(Is1), sizeof...(Is2))>(seq1),
                fill_with_zero_to_reach<std::max(sizeof...(Is1), sizeof...(Is2))>(seq2)))
{ return {}; }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b43d6d726e18984a)